# Biopython MMCIF2Dict return error when reading x,y,z coordinate

Tags: biopython

I am trying to load atom coordinates of protein with PDB_ID 5itp using

```
mmcif_dict = MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict("5itp.cif") 
for i in range(0,len(mmcif_dict["_atom_site.auth_atom_id"])):
    print(mmcif_dict["_atom_site.Cartn_x"][i])
```

It returns an error: IndexError: string index out of range.
Same error pop up for protein 4y7l.

I look at the cif files for these two proteins and find there are two entries for Cartn_x. The first one appears before ATOM coordinates at

```
...
_atom_site.pdbx_PDB_ins_code 
_atom_site.Cartn_x 
_atom_site.Cartn_y 
_atom_site.Cartn_z 
_atom_site.occupancy
...
```

and the second one appears much later at

```
2  2 'Structure model' '_atom_site.Cartn_x'                        
3  2 'Structure model' '_atom_site.Cartn_y'                        
4  2 'Structure model' '_atom_site.Cartn_z'
```

If I delete the second one, MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict works properly. But the problem is it is not practical to modified every such cif files for reading atom coordinate. Does anyone have a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Which version of Biopython are you using? I can reproduce the error with version 1.70 but not with the latest version from Github.

Comment: I install biopython using Anaconda3. The current version of Biopython I am using is 1.70. I tried to update Biopython with either "pip install biopython --upgrade" or "conda update -c conda-forge biopython", but I can't get the up-do-date version and the error remains. Is there anyway of getting the latest version that you are using ?

Comment: You can download the whole module from here: https://github.com/biopython/biopython or just the MMCIF2Dict library alone.

Comment: Thanks. The latest version of MMCIF2Dict library fixes the problem !